# php script test max execution time

Tags: php, linux

2 questions for PHP in Linux:

1.) will register_shutdown_function be called if a script exceeds the maximum time limit for the script to run?

2.) if #1 is true, how can I test a script going beyond its max time limit if sleep() doesn't count towards execution time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A function registered with `register_shutdown_function` will be called when the execution time limit is reached. You can test the limit with a busy wait:

```
<?php
register_shutdown_function(function() {
    echo "shutdown function called\n";
});

set_time_limit(1); // Set time limit to 1 second (optional)
for (;;) ;         // Busy wait
```

Comment: In case you want the wait stop after a while `for ($i=0; $i<100000000; $i++);
  ;`

Comment: @Heikki Naski Well, that would defeat the purpose of testing the time limit, wouldn't it?

Comment: thanks!! an infinite loop - so simple, but I didn't think about it!

Comment: @phihag I usually test these sort of things with a loop that runs sufficiently long time, but not forever. Infinite loops scare me.

Comment: You could also do a while(true) loop. Those go on forever.