# How to find out the Highest limit of request timeout setting allowed by server using PHP?

Tags: php, settimeout

As we do this most of the time to increase the Maximum execution time using php function `set_time_limit` or through `php.ini` settings like `max_execution_time`.
But there is always some maximum limit on server to set this. `phpinfo()` shows us the default max_execution_time set on the server, but sometimes we are allowed to increase it using the methods as described in previous lines. I would like to detect how much execution time setting we are ALLOWED TO INCREASE. I want to detect through PHP script only as I do not have server access and I want to show the proof of this limitation :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never looked into this myself so can't say for sure, but I'm fairly certain that PHP does not have a limit.  Apache/nginx/etc do, however, have limits, so that might be what's killing your script.  And, of course there's the client timeout that you can't control at all.

Comment: if there is at-least any linux command to get this, then we can find it through shell_exec() function or exec() function. As there is always some limitation on server, even it is virtual server hosting or shared hosting.

Comment: create a script, set a value, sleep that value see if it finishes normally, then add to it and try again.

Comment: Also note: Your web server can have other timeout configurations that may also interrupt PHP execution. Apache has a Timeout directive and IIS has a CGI timeout function. Both default to 300 seconds. http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: The question we should all probably really be asking is why do you want to do this?  A very long hanging page is a horrible UX, and there are other options.  (Unless it's just curiosity.)

Comment: ^^ i put all the long jobs in to the background so no one has to sit their waiting.

Comment: The reason to do this is I have already put in the last line as "I want to show the proof of this limitation :)"  
and my script is not working now which was working before because of this timeout limitation. previously database records were less so script was running fine, but now as records got increased, the script takes more time & finally ends to timeout.

Comment: @Dagon how do u put in background? can I have any small example, that would be very helpful.

Comment: move hosts, get a vps, if the hosts sucks, proving it wont help. if you have scripts that regularly time out, then its probably a problem with the script and not the host.

Comment: exec("nohup php file.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to detect the server's default settings, but I'd suggest using something like this:

```
<?php
   $start = time();
   register_shutdown_function(function() {
       $finish = time();
       $total = $finish - $start;
       // Store $total in DB
   });

   set_time_limit(1); // Set time limit to 1 second (optional)
   for (;;) ; 
?>
```

And store the value in a database.  When you initialize the script, see if there's an existing value -- if not run the above as a function and save it.  If one exists, you have your number.

You can find out more about this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666919/php-script-test-max-execution-time) and through PHP's [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php).

Comment: No, not this one. As I said, I want to get max execution time I am  ALLOWED TO INCREASE.